# Static pages in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What are the standard way of making a Ruby on Rails application that will have pages such as

- Home
- About
- Contact

I would appricate if someone had links or an answers rather than just say use a gem because I want to learn how to make simple webapps with such behavior.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Depends on how you want to handle the content in those pages.

**Approach #1 - store content in views**

If you just want to put all your content in ERB views, then a very simple approach is to create a `PagesController` whose purpose is to deal with static pages.  Each page is represented by one action in the controller.

pages_controller.rb:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
match '/home' => 'pages#home'
match '/about' => 'pages#about'
match '/contact' => 'pages#contact'
```

Then create home.html.erb, about.html.erb, and contact.html.erb views under app/views/pages.  These views contain whatever content you want on your static pages.  They'll by default use your app's application.html.erb layout.

You'll also want to look into [page caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#page-caching) to give yourself a boost in performance.

---

**Approach #2 - store content in database**

Another approach I've used is to make a very basic CMS for static pages.  In this case, pages are represented in the model.  It uses the [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to handle slugs for each page so that they can be retrieved by a pretty name in the URL (e.g., /about) rather than by ID.

page.rb:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content

  validates_presence_of :title, :content

  has_friendly_id :title, :use_slug => true, :approximate_ascii => true
end
```

pages_controller.rb:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    render 'shared/404', :status => 404 if @page.nil?
  end
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<%= raw @page.content %>
```

routes.rb:

```
match '/:id' => 'pages#show'
```

Note: put this entry at the end of routes.rb since it matches everything.

Then how you want to create, edit and update pages are up to you - you can have an admin interface, or build it in to your public interface somehow.  This approach can benefit from page caching too.

Comment: You don't even need to include the empty methods in the controller. EDIT: Also, you could put this as a kind of 'catch all' route after everything else: match ':action' => 'pages' to avoid needing to update the routes when you add a new page. However you might want to be careful with that if you have lots of complicated routes.

Comment: Thanks you so much Jeff, that was spot on! The idea I had in mind was the 2. approach but I did not know how to make pretty urls like that. Again thank you!

Comment: You can do something like domain.com/p/blog-post-slug for the match and then match that to `/p/:id`. P is for 'post' and can really be anything. I think this is better than the match anything route.

Comment: What is `:approximate_ascii`?  I can't find documentation on it. However, I assume it uses ASCII to approximate the UTF-8 character, which is default now. https://github.com/FriendlyId/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb

Comment: `@page = Page.find(params[:id])` should be changed to `@page = Page.find_by_id(params[:id])` or you'll just get the default 404 (in public) instead of your custom 404.

Comment: approach 1 is a the way to go  (unless you want a CMS)

Comment: If you use the approach 1, how can do to a form, save it in database, like contact_form or newsletter input?

Comment: @Stanmx you just do a form as always, with your typical "form_tag" helpers.

Comment: @d_rail You can also declare `rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :render_404` and define that method on the controller.

Comment: Excellent. Can we use markdown pages instead of models and database?

Answer (score 23):

Another option is the `high_voltage` gem: https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage

This makes it super easy to create static pages where the content is stored in views.

Answer (score 13):

Jeff's approach #1 (storing content in views and having a route and controller action for each static page) is a good one. The only thing I would add is to use the [`controller` macro](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-controller) in your routes.

So, instead of this:

```
match '/home' => 'pages#home'
match '/about' => 'pages#about'
match '/contact' => 'pages#contact'
```

You can do this:

```
controller :pages do
  get :home
  get :about
  get :contact
end
```

It's two extra lines, yet much so much more elegant, since it eliminates repetition and groups your static page routes together visually.

It also uses the `get` http verb method instead of `match`, [which is a better practice for Rails routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619449/why-use-match-rather-than-get-when-routing-in-rails) (and more concise, now that [Rails 4 requires the http verb to be specified when using `match`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#action-pack).

Answer (score 6):

Check out Michael Hartl's http://railstutorial.org
which comes in a 2.3.8 and 3.0.x version.  It covers this with great examples and leads you through building them very early on and you will also have the opportunity to learn a lot more than this example.
I highly recommend it.

Comment: This now comes in a 3.2 and 4.0 version.

Answer (score 6):

Jeff's Approach #1 works great for me. Here is a trick to make the controller dynamically look up pages. With this, you don't need to touch the controller nor the routes.rb for adding pages. Just drop the pages under app/views/pages and the controller will find it.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render params[:id]
  end
end
```

Comment: This works for me but only when I have the match or get in the routes. Is there something else that needs to be done in order to not have to list all the routes in route.rb? using rails 3.2.12

Comment: Always be wary of what you do with user input. I haven't tested this, but `render` has access to every single view, so I would be worried about a `params[:id]` that looks like `admin/whatever`. FWIW, Rails will automatically render a view without creating a controller action as long as that view exists in the view folder that corresponds to your controller. All you need to do is add the appropriate route, which is not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

config/routes.rb

```
get ':id', to: 'pages#show'
```

app/controllers/pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    begin
      render params[:id]
    rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate
      render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404", :layout => false, :status => :not_found
    end
  end
end
```

Then place your static pages in app/views/pages/{name}.html.erb (or whatever template format.)

Answer (score 0):

An adequate answer to your question would basically look like an introduction to the Rails framework: the MVC structure, templating, and routing DSL at least. Jeff has given a good stab, but his answer still assumes a lot of basic Rails knowledge on your part.

I'd suggest though, that if your webapp is really that simple, Rails might be overkill. I'd look into something lighter, like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), which has a much lower learning curve than Rails and does a great job of this kind of thing without having to deal with complex routing, magic MVC action/template mapping, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For more you can create static pages using [Jekyll bootstrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/usage/jekyll-quick-start.html) or also [Jekyll using Danger blog](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/11744619917/danger-danger-high-voltage-use-rails-3-1-for-static)

Refer it is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding your pages in the public folder so as to be served directly without having to pass through rails at all. I'm not an expert though so I'm not sure if this could have any cons if the page is static.

Comment: This can be called as a crude solution though. This would not allow us to utilize what Rails provides, especially **Common Layout Design** and **Page Caching**. Though, I would not totally discard this solution.

Comment: This technique is lightening fast if you have something like Apache or Nginx configured to serve the pages in your `public` folder, but it forgoes any sort of dynamic content on your pages, like a nav bar which shows the user's logged in/out status.