# Error when creating static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create two static pages and I have the following error:

> Missing template static_pages/index with {:formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:rhtml, :rxml, :builder, :erb, :rjs]} in view paths "F:/assignment/app/views"

I am new to rails and web development in general, so it's probably something simple.

I have followed this link to get to the stage I am now at: [Static pages in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479233/static-pages-in-ruby-on-rails)

I am trying to create two static pages, one called About and one called Help in a basic blog application. When I have created the controller I have called it 'static_pages' as I already have a pages controller.

Can anybody offer any advice on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Where have you stored the view file? and what's its exact name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly if I say you want a path like `localhost:3000/About`

In that case, you want to create a method with the same name as the view (About.html) in your static_pages controller.

```
def About
end
```

(**Notice case sensitivity**)

The About.html file should be placed within the /static_pages directory. And in the routes.rb file, you should have:

```
match '/About' => 'static_pages#About'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have followed that through and I am now getting: The action 'index' could not be found for StaticPagesController. I have then added in an index action, I have tried both Index and index and then then says "Template is missing - Missing template static_pages/index with {:formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:rhtml, :rxml, :builder, :erb, :rjs]} in view paths "F:/assignment/app/views""

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure if I fully understand what you meant though. From which path are you getting the error described above? It just tells you there it can't find the index.html.erb file in `F:/assignment/app/views/static_pages`.

Comment: Sorted now, thanks very much. For some reason I didn't have an index.html.erb file in the static_pages view.