# Why use match rather than get when routing in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, railstutorial.org

In the Ruby on Rails 3 tutorial, the code uses:

```
match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'
match '/signin',  :to => 'sessions#new'
match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'

match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'
```

rather than

```
get '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'
get '/signin',  :to => 'sessions#new'
get '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'

get '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
get '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
get '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'
```

even though all the routes only want the HTTP GET verb. Why not use `get` (or `:via => [:get]` on `match`) and limit the routing action as a matter of practice?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would consider it a best practice to use `get [...]` instead of `match`. As you already mentioned correctly, `match` will create both GET and POST routes. Why create them if you do not need them?

Using the correct matchers (get or post) keeps your routes clean and helps prevent unwanted behavior of your application. The latter point is true especially for POST routes, where you do not want to accidentially put a GET request link on your webpage that can be followed by search bots.

Update [2013-05-12]:
From Rails 4.0 onwards you are now [required to explicitly specifiy the request method](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#action-pack).

Comment: +1 for the rails 4.0 update. Thank you for taking the time to update an old answer.

Comment: Guess now `match` is better if you have routes used for multiple http verbs.

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou Why is that? I know that from time to time, best practices in using a framework shift. However, I do not think this is the case here. If you want to provide both `get`and `post`routes, define them separately using the `get` and `post` keywords. As mentioned in the updated answer, Rails now even forces you to define the request method. I'm not aware of any recent changes in that regard.

Comment: @emrass ok consider the following, `match 'post/:id' => 'post#[action_name]', via: [:get, :post]` isn't it better than writing them separately? where is the almost DRY principle in writing them separately, match is not for all cases but for those that can be combined so if you have the option to combine both routes into one line why not do it? P.S i couldn't come of a good name for action_name, but check this post out,`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722822/route-issue-in-rails-4-about-match-keyword-working-in-rails-3`

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou Now I get your point. You are right - `match` now forces you to specify the request types, so you cannot 'accidentally' create routes you did not intend to use. I agree that `match` now serves as a nice way to generate multiple request types in one statement.