# route issue in rails 4 about match keyword working in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In rails 3 match keyword is working but in rails 4 match keyword is not working for routes

how can i define  these routes  in rails 4

this code segment is working in rails 3

```
match 'admin', :to => 'access#menu'

match 'show/:id', :to => 'public#show'

match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

i need generic formula for rails 4  like in rails 3

```
 match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rails 4 removed generic `match`, you now have to specify which verb you want it to respond to. Typically you'd define your routes as:

```
get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))' => 'foo#matcher'
```

If you want it to use match to get multiple verbs, you can do it like this:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))' => 'foo#matcher', via: [:get, :post]
```

Comment: its not working  with post for these 

 match 'admin', :to => 'access#menu'


match 'show/:id', :to => 'public#show'

Comment: If you're only matching post requests, why use match at all?

Answer (score 6):

What is said in documentation:

In general, you should use the get, post, put and delete methods to constrain a route to a particular verb. You can use the match method with the :via option to match multiple verbs at once:

```
match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: [:get, :post]
```

You can match all verbs to a particular route using via: :all:

```
match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: :all
```

[(documentation)](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bdd518343e3dfaae1dad123db2a55d25773fc278/guides/source/routing.md#http-verb-constraints)

Answer (score 2):

the best way to do this is to first find the output of rake routes

```
$ rake routes
```

you'll get something like this:

```
[rails path] [verb] [url format] [controller#action]
```

so for example:

```
user_show  GET  /show/:id  public#show
```

the action is what you need to look at.  You should be using `get` or `post` rather than `match` - like this:

```
get 'show/:id', :to => 'public#show'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
post ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the questions for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.