# Link_to for static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have made a forum-based website, I want to add a few links to my footer like "more about badges" or "how to ask questions". Well, they are static pages so I really don't want to go through controller to go to those pages. For example, I'd like to view `views/static_pages/badges.html.erb` using `link_to` or other possible tag.

How can I go directly to some page in my views?

Comment: I'd like to suggest `high_voltage` gem, for details check it out: https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage

Comment: Do I really need add a new gem for just two pages? I can simply add an empty method like "badges" to one of my controller and add a page like "badges.html.erb" and link_to badges method. It would be much simpler, I just don't want to do it that way, there has to be a much simpler approach.

Comment: It seems that I'm not alone, it's your choice but specifying a controller for static pages equals to adding the gem. So, there's no loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For static pages you should check out [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) gem. Once it's installed, it'll make a folder `pages` inside your view directory and it'll generate a named route method of `page_path`. For example, if you create a static page `pages/static` then you can refer it to by `page_path('static')` in your views.

EDIT:

If you don't want to use any gem then I'll suggest checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479233/static-pages-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 1):

We do it like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :pages, only: [:show] #-> sends params[:id] as /page_name

#app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
Class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def show
       render "pages/#{params[:id]}"
    end
end
```

This will allow you to call the following:

```
= link_to pages_path("badges") # -> domain.com:3000/pages/badges
```