# jquery ajax "action" as a variable - complex form posting

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

so I have pretty complex form / requierements : I've form (consisting of 4 multiselect boxes) and I want to post that form on the different pages = different controller, according to button clicked - I've 3 buttons = 3 pages. (In those multiselect there are categories and I want to pull out some data from DB accroding to that categories). so what I've now looks like that:

```
 var main = function(){
 function proceed(mapType){  

    switch(mapType) {
    case "showevent" : action = "events/index"; @page = events_path ;  break; //index events 
    case "addplace" : action = "places/new"; @page = new_place_path;  break;
    case "addevent" : action ="events/new"); @page = places_path; break;  //index places = new event
                    }

    $('form').on('submit', function(event){ 
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax('$action', {  //action as variable
              type: 'GET',
      data: $('form').serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result){
        redirect: @page 
            }
        });
     });
  }
 $(document).ready(main);   `
```

Comment: So what's the quesiton?

Comment: question passing action and redirect as variable? I've looked at official jquery documentattion, but I have not found it there - or is this the best approach to do pass some form so its restuls'd affect another website - controller

Comment: The above code is working for you right?

Comment: In the `addevent` case you have a superfluous parenthesis. Moreover you don't use `var` declaration for variables, which causes them to be global instead of staying in the function scope.

Comment: but I mean how to reffer variables in taht jquery is this right ?  `   $('form').on('submit', function(event){ 
          event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax( {
   type: 'GET',
   url: action
          data: $('form').serialize(),
   dataType: 'json",
          success: function(result){
            redirect: page // redirect - bud controller alebo rovno tu
                }
            });   `

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, rename your `.js` file to `.js.erb` to enable ruby expression evaluations. (For more details look at [this Rails Guides page](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns).)

Then, what you need looks roughly like this (not tested, but you can get the idea):

```
    <% url = MyRailsApp::Application.routes.url_helpers %>
    switch(mapType) {
        case "showevent" : action = "events/index"; page = "<%= url.events_path %>";  break; //index events 
        case "addplace" : action = "places/new"; page = "<%= url.new_place_path%>";  break;
        case "addevent" : action ="events/new"; page = "<%= url.places_path %>"; break;  //index places = new event
    }

    // ... use the 'action' and 'page' variables as you need here.
```

Good luck.

EDIT: Added `url` variable. Still you can use [js-routes](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes)

Comment: Try using `rails console` to debug these king of things.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I here's my updated code js-rails is not working, so I turned for this post on SO [Link_to for static pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095215/link-to-for-static-pages) - and in fact this was Zajo's tip so here's my full code `   var main = function(){

```
  function proceed(mapType){  
var action,page;

switch(mapType) { 
    case "showevent" :  action = "events/index"; page = "<%= url.events_path %>" ;  break; //index events 
    case "addplace" :   action = "places/new"; page = "<%= url.new_place_path %>";  break; 
    case "addevent" :   action = "events/new"; page = "<%= url.places_path %>"; break;  //index places = new event(to je v podstate len form)
    // var event_path = "<%#= CGI.unescape url.event_path('{event_id}') %>";
        }  

    $('form').on('submit', function(event){ 
      event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({ 
  type: 'GET',
  url: action,
      data: $('form').serialize(),
  dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result){
        redirect: page // alebo solve in controller 
            }
        });
     });
  }
```

}

$(document).ready(main);
   `   but another problem that rose in the meantime is linking static pages [Link_to for static pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095215/link-to-for-static-pages) and this also (the high_voltage gem did not generate pages folder in view) adn also the 2nd answer won't work