# Do dynamically generated Rails pages from database content become indexable static pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo

I am building a blog application in Rails 4, and I am confused as to whether my pages that are rendered from database content are "static." In other words, I now can generate a view with a "slug" reflective of the title as the params, but my question is: does this page really exist, such that it can be indexed by Googlebot and other sources?

First off, here's what I mean when I am saying that my view is dynamic.

This is a question that comes up a lot, and for example, [Approach #2 in the selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479233/static-pages-in-ruby-on-rails) seems to deal with this head on.

In short, I am storing post content in the `Post` table, and then I show it in the view:

```
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <h2 id="title"><%= post.title %></h2>
            <p id="category"><%= post.category %></p>
            <h5><%= post.author %></h5> at <h5><%= post.published_at %></h5>
            <div id="paragraph"><%= markdown(post.content) %></div>

    <% end %>
```

That renders fine. To get there, I am linking from my home page by appending the slug as a param, like so: `<%= link_to post_path(post.slug), class: "hexIn" do %>`. That works, and we get a URL like localhost:3000/post/example-post-1.

**My Question:** Is that page indexable and in existence to, say, Googlebot, or does it only exist when a user loads that exact link and the page renders?

Answer (score 0):

Google sees the HTML your code and server output. It doesn't know nor care if it was dynamically generated or not. It sees what the browser sees. View your source. That's what Google sees.

But they have to find that page first. So they need to follow a link or find a reference in an XML sitemap.